# split string with whitespace AND multiple other operation signs?

Tags: java

I understand that code such as

```
tokens = mystring.split(\\s);
```

will split the string based on whitespace (or multiple whitespace) and return and array with the tokens in between the spaces. However, I am having trouble understanding how one comes up with these parameters for the split function. How would I specify multiple delimiters?

Specifically, I would like to separate a String and split it with the following delimiters:

- -
- +
- *
- /
- #
- _ (that's an underscore)
- ^ (that's a carrot)

Yes, if you're wondering I am trying to implement a postfix calculator using a stack. But thats not the point...the point is I am having trouble understanding how one comes up with the parameters for the split method. Are there any great resources out there that explain this?

Thank you. If this is a duplicate, I apologize. (most questions regarding the split method involved a specific question, not a general explanation of how it works)

Comment: What do you mean by specify multiple delimiters? Could you provide an example of a `String` and how you would want to split it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the regular expression first. For basic use it is very simple :) For your requirement you can split it with `String[] split = mystr.split("[-+*/#_^]");`  The square brackets provides a list of characters to match, if any one of the character in that square bracket match then it is a match.

Comment: could you explain why you used square brackets?

Comment: Now that you asked about it, I also found that there is redundancy :) the square brackets provides for `any of` (a list), so no need for the pipe. Updated the answer.

Comment: I have one more question, if you don't mind...how would I combine the functionality of String[] split = mystr.split("[-+*/#_^]");              and something like String[] split = mystr.split("\\s"); into one line?

Comment: I guess you want to split on white space also along with all other, if so it is simple just add that `\\s` also to the list, ie., `[-+*/#_^\\s]`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you have probably read in other answers, the `split` method takes regex meaning the `String` passed in will be interpreted differently than a normal sequence of characters. Some of your desired delimiters are known as meta characters which means you have to escape them by putting a `\\` before.

For example, suppose you had the following string:

`String string = "this+is+a+string";`

And you wanted to split the string by the `+` signs. Taking into considering that `+` is a meta character, you have to escape it:

`String[] split = string.split("\\+");`

And the values would be:

```
split[0] = "this"
split[1] = "is"
split[2] = "a"
split[3] = "string"
```

I'm unsure of what you mean by 'multiple delimiters' but hopefully this could provide some insight on what you are trying to do.

Comment: This explanation was very straightforward and it makes a lot of sense. How do you know if a character is a meta character? Is this common knowledge or is this something I can reference in some online database/resource?

Comment: @user2734823 Well, you may look at [this](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php) as a reference; it lists all the meta characters.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Java documentation page for [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), it seems that you can use this regex to filter by any punctuation:

```
\p{Punct}   Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Here is some sample code that I ran to test this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] vars = "a+b#c_d^e/f*g-h".split("\\p{Punct}");

    for (String var : vars) {
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}
```

with output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

So to split by punctuation *or* by whitespace just use `.split("\\s|\\p{Punct}");` This is because the pipe symbol | stands for or in regex. If you have any questions about my answer feel free to comment below and I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need complicated regular expressions to parse simple math expressions. `StringTokenizer` suffices for parsing such expressions. Since you are going to make a postfix calculator, you will probably want to disregard white space and return back all the operators like `*`, `+` and so on.

Here is the `split` function

```
public static List<String> split(String line, String delim, boolean includeDelim, boolean removeWhiteSpace) {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(line, delim, includeDelim);

    while (parser.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = parser.nextToken();
        if (removeWhiteSpace) {
            token = token.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        }
        tokens.add(token);
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

Above function lets you specify whether you want all the delimiters back or the part in between delimiters. You can choose to disregard white space too.

And here is my main function

```
public static void main(String aa[]) {
    final String DELIM = "+-*/^#_";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(">" + split(line, DELIM, true, true));
    }
}
```

Some sample output

```
12 ^ 36 - 15 + 17
>[12, ^, 36, -, 15, +, 17]

500*6/3+2
>[500, *, 6, /, 3, +, 2]
```

I am getting all those delimiters back. You can manipulate the list returned by the `split` function.